# Statics in ES2015 classes

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on a React application using [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) and experiencing an issue when using two static methods which are [willTransitionTo()](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#-willtransitionto-transition-params-query-callback-) and [willTransitionFrom()](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#-willtransitionfrom-transition-component-callback-).

The point is that this **doesn't** work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Router from 'react-router'

export default class extends Component {
  static willTransitionTo() {
    console.log('hi');
  }

  static willTransitionFrom() {
    console.log('bye');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>hello!</div>
  }
}
```

But this do:

```
export default React.createClass({
  statics: {
    willTransitionTo() {
      console.log('hi');
    },

    willTransitionFrom() {
      console.log('bye');
    }
  },

  render() {
    return <div>hello!</div>
  }
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just to clarify, what's happening is that `willTransitionTo` and `willTransitionFrom` are being triggered when written in es5 way; otherwise, they doesn't trigger. What is the syntax difference? Ideias?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Classes *do* have static methods: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions (linking to the draft because I can't connect to ecma).

Comment: @FelixKling oh wow I'm so confused, I need to get some sleep. Totally mixed up with static properties. Heck, I used static methods in code today 0_0, good night.

Comment: Could be a bug in react-router, though I wonder what the `React.createClass` approach does differently.

Comment: It happens, @BenjaminGruenbaum, lol. Anyway, thank you guys. I posted [this issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1649) on their repo—let's see what happens. Last but not least, I'll be using es5 meanwhile.